# stack & unstack undefined in Julia DataFrames?

Tags: dataframe, julia

Coming back to Julia DataFrames after a while.

I can't run my old code, as on `stack` and `unstack` I got the error:

`ERROR: UndefVarError: stack not defined`

`stackdf` and `unstackdf` instead work, but they produce something slightly different, a view instead of a copy of the dataframe.

Have `stack` and `unstack` been removed? But I can still see them in the documentation..

Comment: They are both defined. Can you please give a full example of your session that raises this error along with Julia and DataFrames .jl version information?

Answer (score 0):

The "problem" is when `DataFrames` is imported among with `IndexedTables` (e.g., `using DataFrames, IndexedTables`) as both packages export `stack()`/`unstack()` functions and so its usage must be qualified using the full package/function name (e.g. `DataFrames.stack()`).

To be honest there is warning on this when both modules are imported, so just my fault I didn't see it (on my excuse, the same code was working before without problems).